# Model parameter selection for time series data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

For model parameter selection, we always make a grid-search with cross validation to test which parameters are better than others.

It's right for general training data, like [this one](https://www.kaggle.com/c/shelter-animal-outcomes), but if data has time relationship with each other, like sells over days or stock over days, is that wrong to do cross validation directly?

As cross validation will use kFold which split randomly in training data, which means for time series data, recent days info will be used for training on old days.

How to do parameter selection, or cross validation on time series data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's more common to use backtesting or rolling forecasting, in which you train on either the previous N time periods or else all of the periods up to N, and then test on period N+k (k>=1), or possibly even test on a range of future periods. (e.g., train on the past 60 months of data, and then predict the next 12 months). But the details really depend on the models you're using and the problem domain. Rob Hyndman gives [a concrete example](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscvexample/), and you can find many more by searching for "kaggle contest time series data cross validation."

In some cases, it makes sense to perform a random split stratified by time. Then perform the rolling training and CV evaluation as described above on the train split, and separately perform a rolling test evaluation on the random test holdout.

In some cases, you can get away with performing ordinary random CV where time is just another feature value (often encoded as many engineered time features, such as `cos(2 pi hour_of_day / 24)`, `sin(2 pi hour_of_day / 24)`, `cos(2 pi hour_of_week / 168)`, etc.). This tends to work better with models such as XGBoost, allowing the model to discover the time dependencies in the data instead of encoding them in the train/test regimen.

Comment: thanks a lot :) I wonder for the second and third paragraph: do you think sometimes we could ignore date info and do cv directly, even though some training data may come from date behind test date? then in what scenarios I could do this and still believe cv result ?

Comment: I think it's safe to do this whenever all the observations are completely independent (but then, it's not much of a time series, just data that happens to have a date attribute). Whenever the current observation is in someway related to or influenced by previous data, ignoring the dates will lead to leakage.